# Oil burner Fuel line adjustment

Tags: boiler

In my crawlspace, I have an oil tank at the front of the house, with the fuel line running to the rear of the house where the oil burner is located. Fuel line is on the floor, running mostly along a wall.

I am currently putting in foam board wall insulation and the fuel line makes a turn right next to a corner, preventing me from adding any foam board. Fuel line looks to be metal pipe that was unspooled, as it is not straight at all along the run.

Is this something that falls within the purview of a plumber and can they adjust it easily? To put it another way, i just need the turn to start further away from the wall.

Comment: A well focused picture or two would help people to understand what kind of fuel line you're working with. Something flexible is _likely_ copper, but (not an HVAC expert by any means) that sounds odd to me for fuel oil. Any sort of rigid pipe is not likely to have the bends I'm envisioning from your description. A picture is worth 1000 words, as the saying goes...

Comment: Did the oil burner show some errors/problems? Was there any change that influenced the throughput through the oil line? Air pockets could be a problem, as well as a mismatch of inner diameter and oil throughput. Dependent on the location, if the pipe is outside the insulation, it could be a problem in the winter, since it does no more profit from the heat losses of the wall.